# Safari does not restore tabs / not Resuming

Tags: safari, resume, tabs

It seems my Safari is not resuming correctly.

I open some tabs, then quit and when fire up Safari again it's opened like wasn't have any tabs opened before.

Is it some version bug, or i should look for something in Safari prefs?

- Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)
- MOX 10.7.4 (Build 11E53)

EDIT:
In reaction to Michiel i've checked whether i have Resume turned on.
[image: System preferences -> General]

Comment: Is restoring windows when quitting and re-opening apps unchecked in the general preferences? Does `defaults read com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows` return 0?

Comment: http://git.io/csCr6w -- is there some clean way to fix it? I don't want to do it via shell

Comment: I just thought NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows might have been set to false. But since there was no key for it, it's something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's working again.

Steps i did:

- Disable and Enable again resume in System preferences → General
- Enable and Disable again extensions in Safari → Preferences. I don't have any extensions installed. The "abling" was just about the Safari's functionality
  [image: Abling Extensions in Safari]

I don't know what of these steps fixed it, but now it simply works :/

P.S.: Back to  Lauri Ranta's check. It has still same result

```
defaults read com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows                                                                                                                     
2012-06-19 11:13:35.069 defaults[2240:707] 
The domain/default pair of (/Users/mailo/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist, NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows) does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a setting in Safari, but a general setting. Go to your **System Preferences < General** and make sure **Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps** is checked on.

[image]

But you can install some 3th party apps too.

- There is [SafariRestore](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/34144/safarirestore), which will basically do the same. But you **have** to disable the **Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps** on the screenshot above!
- You can also add the [Sessions](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8247646/sessions/index.html) extension to Safari which will do the same.

I haven't any experience with neither of these apps, so please let me know if it works out!

Comment: Unfortunately i have it enabled (see updated question)

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. It works for me with great ease. I'll check for more solutions...

Comment: Last week or so it was working for me also

Comment: What did you do in the mean time? (Install or delete something?)

Comment: See my edited answer!

Comment: I found a questionable fix. Now it works, but thank you. The only thing which could cause this, could be the recent Safari update. I wasn't doing any system invasive stuff for a long time, maybe for all the time i have it installed ;)

Comment: Ok, great if you solved your own question! Good luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

I found another workaround, although I'm not sure why this worked or even if it actually worked or was simply a coincidence.

What I did was: Restore Safari (in the main Safari menu). I had every box checked except the ones about location and saving passwords. So it was sort of an "erase".
Then I quit Safari en started it again. Now it works again, correctly resuming all tabs I had open.